# Transmission Swap - Nissan Rogue Sport - Warranty still intact?

Tags: transmission, nissan, swap

My wife and I purchased a Rogue Sport in the US and, though we love the vehicle for the space, were dismayed that we couldn't find it in a manual transmission.

In looking at Nissan UK - it appears that a 6 speed manual is available. So, OEM transmission and parts exist. If a dealership made the swap, would the factory powertrain warranty still be valid?

Comment: I personally doubt it. But maybe try contacting them?

Comment: Definitely a question you have to ask Nissan - they may have a reason for not selling the manual in the States - like it’s less than 1% of sales so not worth it...

Comment: @SolarMike, I'm absolutely sure that they don't offer a manny in the States because of the sheer lack of sales volume. But given that there are OEM parts - the swap doesn't appear to be THAT complex. I was hoping someone had attempted this with Nissan or other - but will definitely pose the question to Nissan.

Comment: I think the swap will be more complex than you think. The trans, pedals, cabling, interior panel replacements, shift lever assembly, modifications or replacement of the wiring harness (A dealer probably won't modify the harness), a new ECM with calibrations... can possibly impact other modules due to how cars are these days. Then you're possibly paying the dealer to do this? People in the past have definitely done transmission swaps auto to manual, they either have deep pockets or a lot of time on their hands.  Not saying it wouldn't be a fun project to tackle yourself though.

Comment: @Ben, good points. My rationale for using as much dealer service as possible is to maintain the warranty. I'd love to do as much work as I possibly can on the project to save some money. If the warranty goes out the window regardless, then it's a project I'll do myself.

Comment: It may not entirely void the warranty and I suspect if it came down to it you'd have to fight for the warranty to be honored. In the US at least (IIRC) you can modify a car and the dealer can't void a warranty unless it had a direct impact on the failed system.